# Is it correct to say "the mattress is bulging, get it flat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

[image]
You put your mattress on the bed but it is not flat or level

Is it correct to say "the mattress is bulging, get it flat"?

Comment: Is it the mattress though that you're talking about? It looks like the bedding (bedclothes) is rumpled as if someone had sat or laid on it.

Comment: Mostly, but you'd need some additional punctuation -- "The mattress is bulging. Get it flat." Otherwise you have a run-on sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the bedding is rumpled and the mattress is bulging

Comment: I wouldn't use ***bulging*** in such contexts. Maybe ***Flatten/Smooth out** that **lumpy** mattress!* But by the looks of it it's just a bit ***[c]rumpled***, hardly lumpy / bulging at all.

Comment: **Get it flat** sounds awkward and non-fluent to this US English speaker.  **Get it (adjective)** doesn't usually mean **make it (adjective)** outside of a few stock phrases (*get it right/wrong, get it ready*) and overuse and misuse of **get** is a common trait of English learners.  Use **make** or find another verb that means what you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA **had laid on it** or **had lain on it**? Is this just a US -UK thing?

Comment: @RonaldSole alas, it is a lay–lie thing. I got the verbs mixed up, indeed it should have been *had lain*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note in passing that this is framed as an order and is very abrupt. A solider or  prisoner might be told this by an irate officer.

An equally abrupt (but more idiomatic) order would be,

"The mattress is bulging, flatten it!"